# How to proxy a Create React App project to pull from ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a React project which I am trying to pull data from an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. Using Swagger from .Net I can call

```
https://localhost:7119/Sitemap
```

and get the correct results. When I try to access this same URL from React using a proxy, I am getting a `<!Doctype...` back, that being the root `index.html` used for React.

Here is my fetch call:

```
await fetch("sitemap", {
        method: 'GET'
        , headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        , credentials: 'include'
// ADDED 
        , redirect: 'follow'
        , mode: 'cors'
    })
        .then(resp => {
            let tmp = resp.json();
            return tmp;
        })
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ActionTypes.SITEMAP_LOADED,
                payload: res
            })
        })
```

and my setupProxy.js:

```
/*
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/*', {
        target: 'https://localhost:7119/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: "debug"
    }));
    // mock(app);
};
*/

//**** This has been modified to:
const contexts= {
    "/Sitemap"
}
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware(contexts, {
        target: 'https://localhost:7119/',
        secure:true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: "debug"
    }));
    // mock(app);
};
```

Coming from a strict C# web application background, I am completely lost when it comes to proxying calls from another server. In fighting with this I have also received CORS errors (putting the full path in the fetch statement) which I believe using `createProxyMiddleware` will eliminate.

From what I have read it has something to do with the path as the request header is attempting to pull from `http://localhost:3000/sitemap` without defaulting to the proxy.

How can this be corrected?

**Update**

After making changes suggested I am now getting an error message reflected in my command prompt. Each requested file generates 2 messages:
`[HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/manifest.json to https://localhost:7119/ [DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT]`

and

`[HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/manifest.json to https://localhost:7119/ [ECONNREFUSED]`

Comment: `sitemap` is not `Sitemap`. I would also prefix it with a `/` to ensure it's not a relative URL to whatever your current page is

Comment: _"attempting to pull from http://localhost:3000/sitemap"_... yep, that's how proxies work. To the client, the requests look local. FYI ASP.NET has built-in CORS support if you enable it

Comment: I didn't think URL's in the windows environment were case sensitive?  I will look at that first thing in the morning. As for CORS and Proxies I know next to nothing :(

Comment: have you tried createProxyMiddleware({ ........ secure: false, })? what's the error message you've got?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Yes I have. There is no Error message except it cannot parse the original html page (<!Doctype....) as JSON. Simply put it is not going to the /sitemap by proxy but just reloading the main page.

Comment: @Phil Changing to `fetch(/Sitemap...` now gives me 'Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/Sitemap'. I am getting the same error for manifest.json and favicon.ico. Swagger still works however so it's not an error in the server code but rather the proxying.

Answer (score 0):

So what I have done is enabled CORS in my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("CORS",policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
```

Then in my fetch I made a direct call to `https://localhost:7119/Sitemap`. This is enabling me to get a response. It is not an ideal solution as it will not port to production without changes and makes all future API calls cumbersome but it does work.

I have a lot more research to pursue to get the proxy working correctly but for now I have the function that I need.